# mssql_num_row requires 1 parameter to be resourced

Tags: php, sql

Here is my code:

```
    $link=mssql_connect($server, 'username','password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to the mssql database, it could be offline! ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
mssql_select_db('GunzDB', $link);
$result="SELECT * FROM Account WHERE UserID = '$username'";

if(mssql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "That username is already in use!";
} else{
    $result="SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Email = '$email'";

    if(mssql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "That email is already in use!";
    } else{

        $query="INSERT INTO Account (UserID, UGradeID, PGradeID, RegDate, Name, Email) VALUES ('" . $username . "','0','0','00:00','" . $name . "','" . $email . "')";
        if($query){
            $result="SELECT * FROM Account WHERE UserID = '$username'";

            $row = mssql_fetch_array($result);
            $AID=$row['AID'];
            $query="INSERT INTO Login (AID, Password) VALUES ('" . $AID . "','" . $password . "')";
            if($query){
                echo "<span style='color: lime'>Your account has been successfully created!</span>";
            } else{
                echo "error with MSSQL: " . mssql_get_last_message();
            }
        } else{
            echo "error with MSSQL: " . mssql_get_last_message();
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting these errors

```
Warning: mssql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /var/www/gunz/register.php on line 81

Warning: mssql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /var/www/gunz/register.php on line 86

Warning: mssql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /var/www/gunz/register.php on line 94
```

it has to do with these rows

```
$result="SELECT * FROM Account WHERE UserID = '$username'";

$result="SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Email = '$email'";

$result="SELECT * FROM Account WHERE UserID = '$username'";
```

Comment: Why your code is so much shifted to the right? It's hardly readable

Comment: Dude, I just formatted your code, and when tidiing it I realised you are missing a few braces (2 at the end...) please use a IDE to avoid that kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't execute any query :

```
$result= "SELECT * FROM Account WHERE UserID = '$username'";
if (mssql_num_rows($result) > 0){
```

it should be :

```
$result = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM Account WHERE UserID = '$username'");
if (mssql_num_rows($result) > 0){
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not give a string as input to `mssql_num_rows`

it should be a resource obtained after doing `mssql_query`

like

```
$query = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM a');

echo mssql_num_rows($query);
```

and not

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM a';

echo mssql_num_rows($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not using mssql_query() function.

use this:

```
$result=mssql_query("SELECT * FROM Account WHERE UserID = '$username'");

$result=mssql_query("SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Email = '$email'");

$result=mssql_query("SELECT * FROM Account WHERE UserID = '$username'");
```